# getting started with oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

[image]
**I've downloaded oracle database and when I click on get started I get this message , how can I fix it ?**

Comment: did you create a database, is it running? that link is trying to load a web page that's served by a running copy of Oracle Database. It has an internal web listener that can serve pages like Application Express (APEX) for web development and EM Express for db management.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you haven't started a database.